# how to run two arrays at the same time in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I created two CCArray,
CCArray *allieArray;
CCArray *enemyArray;

and I know if I do in my update method,

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(allieArray, allie)
    {
        //do something1 here 
    }

    CCARRAY_FOREACH(enemyArray, enemy)
    {
        //do something 2 here
    }
}
```

it will go through "do something1" first, finish "do something1", then go through "do something2".
now I want to have to system to go through "do something1" and "do something2" at the same time, is it even possible?

UPDATE, just to not have you confuse by my post, I did meant multithreading. Cheers guys =)

Comment: FYI: The correct spelling of "allie" is "ally", plural "allies"

Answer (score 0):

You mean a nested for loop?

```
CCARRAY_FOREACH(allieArray, allie)
{
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(enemyArray, enemy)
    {
        //do something to 1 and 2 here
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for editing my text, I knew it looks kind of weird, but I didn't know how to correct it.

Comment: second, thank you for your fast replying. But this way it would draw back a lot of performance, if I have 200 object for both arrays, the frame rate would drop to 20 fps in my 5th iPod touch. So, my original idea is, have enemyArray running enemy's position, and sent the current position information to the allieArray, then in the allieArray calculate ccpDistance(between the allie.position and the position that sent by the enemyArray), and decide it should attack or not.can I do it or is there a way around to iterate array within an array?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean multithreading. You can enumerate each array in a separate thread, which means on a dual core device each array would have its own CPU to work on, and enumeration would end faster.

If you meant to say "both at the exact same time" then that's physically impossible to guarantee, and impractical to attempt.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant (multithreading), but if I do it this way, it will only be able to run on iPhone 4S and iPhone 5 right? Can you suggest me a link where to learn how to do this? (Also, thank you for the great book you wrote, it helps me tons, definitely worth every cents =))